# What is disadvantage of calling sleep() inside mutex lock?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization, coverity

For example:

```
pthread_mutex_lock();
//Do something
sleep(1);                //causes issues waiting while holding lock

pthread_mutex_unlock();
```

what is the solution if we don't want to use sleep inside mutex lock

Comment: A language issue from my side perhaps, but what is a "*coverity issues*"?

Comment: The solution is to not sleep.

Comment: @alk I think that one: https://scan.coverity.com/  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity

Comment: A better question would be "Why would anyone be calling sleep() inside a mutex lock". I have absolutely no idea why anyone would do that.

Comment: To answer this question completely, we need to know why you were calling sleep() while holding a lock in the first place.

Comment: I've written a lot of multithreaded apps over decades, and I can't rememeber all the design details, but I'm 100% sure that I have never called Sleep() inside a lock.

Comment: The  most likely reason he is calling sleep is to make sure that the mutex is held for an appreciable time so he can see how the mutex works/check the lock is working. It's not unusual to call `sleep` in a test case for example if you want to test what happens if something takes longer than expected.

Comment: @Ben Why would you use a static analyser on your lab/test/junk code though? Such tools should only be used on production quality code (unless one loves to waste time chasing non-issues).

Comment: @Lundin He's obviously a beginner, as we all once were. The answer for him is to ignore this warning or use a pragma or exclusion list to disable it. He's sleeping in a mutex because he is learning about mutexes, and he's running coverity on it because he is learning about coverity. There is no mystery here.

Comment: @Ben If you say so. I can't read the OP's mind so I'll refrain from guessing the reasons why.

Comment: It is calling sleep because it is waiting for database to be ready.
consider it like:
mutex_lock()
fun1() //calling fun1()
mutex_unlock()

fun1()
{
do
{
e = sql_db_ready()
wait()
cnt++;
}while(cnt < 10);

Comment: In above comment , fun1() contains wait() which is sleep() for 1 seconds

Comment: I think there are better ways to wait for an event. This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid sleep in this scenario? or do i have to use pthread_cond_wait instead of sleep

Comment: @GaneshNaik There ought to be a better way to wait for the db to be ready than a check-and-sleep loop, but that's not important right now; for purpose of this question, what I still need to know is, why does this lock need to be held while you wait for the db?  What other concurrent operation could you be racing with if you didn't hold the lock?

Answer (score 7):

As a rule of thumb, you usually (but not always) don't want to hold a mutex for a long period of time (otherwise, other threads locking the same mutex would wait too long), and a full second is a long period for a processor doing billions of elementary operations each second.

You might want to use [condition variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) (since [pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) is [*atomically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) releasing the mutex), or do the `sleep` (or some [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) outside of the locked region. You might even -on Linux- use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s -or the cheaper but Linux-specific [eventfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html)- to communicate between threads running event loops.

The [coverity static source analyzer](https://scan.coverity.com/) is heuristic and might give false alarms.

Take time to read a good [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/).